# Windows Form application hangs while receiving serial data

Tags: c#, winforms, freeze

I am from Embedded domain and need to make a GUI for my device. I have written firmware for the device in C and making GUI application using Visual C# Windows Form Application. Device is sending data to serial port at 100ms and I am trying to receive the data in winforms.

Data:

```
10Q20Q30Q40Q50Q60Q70Q80Q90Q100Q110Q120Q130Q140Q150Q
```

I have written following C# code to receive it.

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  //Using data receive event handler to receive data               
  serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(comPort_DataReceived);
}
```

Then in `comPort_DataReceived` I am calling Read()

```
void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    Read();

}

delegate void Callbackmessage();
void Read()
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
      Callbackmessage abc = new Callbackmessage(Read);
      this.Invoke(abc);
  }
  else
  {
    String data = serialPort1.ReadLine();

  }
```

So finally I am reading the data and saving it into `String data`. The application is working fine but it is hanging like buttons are responding after 1sec. If I comment this line `String data = serialPort1.ReadLine();` , then the application works smoothly. Why the application is hanging. I don't know any other way of receving data from serial port.  Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It's hanging because you're doing an i/o operation on the main UI thread that's taking some time. Consider doing this operation in a task (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @auburg Thanks I'll definitely try this. Actually I have just started learning Visual C# so I am looking for resource so that I can learn

Answer (score 0):

You can use a background worker. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx
and do the read in the bacground worker RunAsync 
e.Result = serial.ReadLine()
and in the backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted eventHandler you can grab the information and report it back to the client

Answer (score 0):

General suggestion is to use async IO and `port.BaseStream.BeginRead`. There is a number of Async wrappers around Serial port. For example you can look at this [one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84319/async-serialport-wrapper). [Here](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport) also a sample of async usage.